# nodejs: API differences fs.readFile vs. http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

Node.js has no built-in promises support. Eventual promise implementations are up to the user. The promise library Q supports some helper functions to convert node-style (err, succ) functions to promise objects.

The q documentation shows this with the fs.readFile function like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var q = require("q");

q.nfcall(fs.readFile, "/path/file")
.then(_ => console.log("succ"))
.fail(_ => console.log("err"))
.done();
```

This works well. Yet transferring this structure to, say, the http.get function is not possible, since it has natively another structure:

```
var http = require("http");
http.get("http://url..", succ_funct).on("error", err_funct);
```

This is already a "sort of" (!) promise style notation.
I'm asking myself if there is a reason for those different API types in node.js . Considering the examples shown above, it would be more consistent to write something like this:

```
q.nfcall(http.get, "http://url..")
.then(succ_f)
.fail(err_f)
.done();
```

Comment: _Node.js has no built-in promises support_ Unless you're still using 0.* , that's not true.. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Comment: _This is already a "sort of" (!) promise style notation_ those from the `http.get` are callbacks, and some of the benefits of using promises is to avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)

Comment: @mmm I think that he means that the Node.js standard library (`fs`, `http`, etc) doesn't use promises yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` uses the common Node callback idiom where a callback gets called with an error object as first argument (if there were errors), or the result of the function (the file data) as second argument.

The optional function that gets passed to `http.get()` <s>(only one, not two as you're suggesting)</s> is a shortcut for adding an *event handler function* for the `response` event.

In other words, #1 is a shortcut for #2:

```
// #1
var client = http.get(URL, function(res) { ... });

// #2
var client = http.get(URL);
client.on('response', function(res) { ... });
```

Event handler functions and "regular" callbacks are different beasts. Event handlers are commonly used for streams (`http.get()` returns a stream).

Errors on streams may occur somewhere during the lifetime of the stream, so you don't use regular callbacks for streams (which imply that once the callback gets called, any errors have already occurred). Also, the result isn't necessarily available immediately (which requires reading the stream data "manually").

There are also stream-based API's for files (like [`fs.createReadStream()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)).

Comment: * as you're suggesting - sorry, that was my mistake. I updated the post. Now the whole concern hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: the question is: why are they different beasts? What is the design concept behind this? Reading a file, well this can succeed or this can fail. Making a http request, this can succeed or fail as well. You know, what's the philosophy behind the distinct API's for these purposes in one framework like nodejs.

Comment: @AntonHarald I added some more info on the differences.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I'm starting to see the difference. Maybe http.get was a bad example, because it's already a shorthand for http.request - the later shows more of the "stream-character".

Comment: http.request(options).on("response", succ_f).on("error", err_f).end(); This is actually the syntax I was looking for, since it clearly separates  asynchronous events in a similar fashion like the q library does.

Comment: @AntonHarald to make things more complicated: you can also get errors on the response object (the one that gets passed as argument to the `response` event handler). For instance, if the server closes the connection while reading the response data.

Comment: it's actually not making it more complicated, rather giving another reason for the design of the api: In a http get request, there can be two kinds of errors: either in the request itself (i.g. there's no internet connection or the url is not valid), or - as you pointed out - in the actual response of the server. good to keep that in mind.